# How can I open 'Save as' dialog box for an Image in Chrome with the following Code by just using client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code for demo, I have added a button to save Image so that whenever User click that save as dialog box should appear to save and download the given image on Client System.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <h3>A demonstration of how to access an IMG element</h3>

    <img id="myImg" src="img_pulpit.jpg" alt="The Pulpit Rock" width="304" height="228">

    <p>Click the button to get the URL of the image.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

    <button onclick="saveImage()">Save Image</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myImg").src;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
    function saveImage(){
    window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/img_pulpit.jpg").document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, "#myImg")
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is in your paremeters.. try the following.

window.open("https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/img_pulpit.jpg").document.execCommand('SaveAs, 'true',$("#myImg").val())

Comment: Nope , it's still the same result. It willl just open another tab with that Image but not the dialog box required

Comment: you can try on this link  'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_get'